# Is it possible to isolate this variable from this equation?

Tags: arithmetic, problem-solving

Can someone with strong knowledge of math answer me?

I need to isolate $x$ from this equation:

$a = \dfrac{b((1+x)^n - 1)}{ x(1 + x)^n}$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use MathJax to format your equations. It's very important to show what you have tried. It is possible that there is no solution to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to fully isolate $x$ because there will always be some $x$ either to the power of $n$ or to the root of $n$, but here's as far as you can go:

Let's begin by dividing both sides by $b$:

$$\frac{a}{b} = \frac{(1+x)^n - 1}{ x(1 + x)^n}$$

Break the right side into two fractions:

$$\frac{a}{b} = \frac{(1+x)^n}{ x(1 + x)^n} - \frac{1}{ x(1 + x)^n}$$

Simplify the first fraction on the right:

$$\frac{a}{b} = \frac{1}{x} - \frac{1}{x(1 + x)^n}$$

I think it's  impossible to make any progress after that.